# Trying to find and separate menu into new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have record of `menu_categories` and `menu` tables as INNER JOIN query result. Trying to find similar data and make separate array of menu, but not able to. Here is my code below

**Code**

```
    $arr1 = [];
    $arr2 = [];

    foreach($menu as $allmenu)
    {
        $cat_id = $allmenu->menu_category_id;
        foreach($allmenu as $key => $value)
        {
            if($key === 'menu_category_id' && $cat_id === $allmenu->menu_category_id)
            {
             $arr1[] = [
                'menu_name'=> $allmenu->menu_name,
                'link' => $allmenu->link,
                'icon' => $allmenu->icon,
                ];
            }
        }
         $arr2['new_menu_array'][] = $arr1;
    }
```

**Query Result**

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [category_name] => Settings
        [category_icon] => 
        [menu_name] => Create settings
        [link] => /create_settings
        [menu_category_id] => 1
        [icon] => Cgear
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [category_name] => Settings
        [category_icon] => 
        [menu_name] => Edit settings
        [link] => /edit_settings
        [menu_category_id] => 1
        [icon] => Egear
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [category_name] => Users
        [category_icon] => 
        [menu_name] => Create user
        [link] => /create_user
        [menu_category_id] => 2
        [icon] => Chuman
    )
```

)

**Trying to achieve**

```
  Array
  (
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [category_name] => Settings
        [category_icon] =>
        [new_menu_array] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [menu_name] => Create settings
                [link] => /create_settings
                [icon] => Cgear
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [menu_name] => Edit settings
                [link] => /edit_settings
                [icon] => Egear
            )                
        )
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [category_name] => Users
        [category_icon] => 
        [new_menu_array] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [menu_name] => Create user
                [link] => /create_user
                [icon] => Chuman
            )
        )
    )
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your menus, and check if `$arr['category_id]` already exists. If not, create it. Then you append your `new_menu_array[]` data to that menu. Here's a working example:

```
<?php
$json = '[{"category_name":"Settings","category_icon":"","menu_name":"Create settings","link":"/create_settings","menu_category_id":1,"icon":"Cgear"},{"category_name":"Settings","category_icon":"","menu_name":"Edit settings","link":"/edit_settings","menu_category_id":1,"icon":"Egear"},{"category_name":"Users","category_icon":"","menu_name":"Create user","link":"/create_user","menu_category_id":2,"icon":"Chuman"}]';

$menus = json_decode($json);

$arr = [];

foreach ($menus as $menu) {
    $categoryId = $menu->menu_category_id;
    if (!isset($arr[$categoryId])) {
        $obj = new stdClass();
        $obj->category_name = $menu->category_name;
        $obj->category_icon = $menu->category_icon;
        $obj->new_menu_array = [];
        
        $arr[$categoryId] = $obj;
    }

    $arr[$categoryId]->new_menu_array[] = [
        'menu_name' => $menu->menu_name,
        'link' => $menu->link,
        'icon' => $menu->icon
    ];
}

// Reset array keys to make sure they start from 0
$arr = array_values($arr);

print_r($arr);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_name] => Settings
            [category_icon] => 
            [new_menu_array] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [menu_name] => Create settings
                            [link] => /create_settings
                            [icon] => Cgear
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [menu_name] => Edit settings
                            [link] => /edit_settings
                            [icon] => Egear
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_name] => Users
            [category_icon] => 
            [new_menu_array] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [menu_name] => Create user
                            [link] => /create_user
                            [icon] => Chuman
                        )

                )

        )

)
```